# How to draw a graph in R language with labels in X-axis

Tags: r, csv

I have the following data in .csv file:

```
Name  marks1 marks2    
xy      10    30
yz      20    40
zx      30    40
vx      20    20
vt      10    20
```

How do I draw a graph with both `marks1` and `marks2` in y-axis and name in x-axis?

```
y <- cbind(data$marks1,data$marks2)
x <- cbind(data$Name)
matplot(x,y,type="p")
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you've already tried.

Comment: Have you tried ?plot in R console?

Comment: y <- cbind(data$Marks1,data$Marks2)
x <- cbind(data$Name)
matplot(x,y,type="p")

Comment: Please edit that code into your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility using ggplot:

```
## Creating your dataset
Name <-c("xy","yz","zx","vx","vt")
marks1 <- c(10,20,30,20,10)
marks2 <- c(30,40,40,20,20)

## Combine the data into a data frame
data <- data.frame(Name,marks1,marks2)

## Loading libraries 
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

## Reshape the data from wide format to long format
redata <- melt(data,id="Name")
redata

## plot your data 
ggplot(redata,aes(x=Name,y=value))+geom_point(aes(color=variable))+ylab("Marks")
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

**Updated for the file read**

If you have a file with the above data then you can read your data using the following command:
I am assuming your file has a extension *.csv and is spaced by commas.

```
data <- read.table("mydata.csv",header=T,sep=",")
```

or you directly use the following code for csv files

`data <- read.csv("mydata.csv")`

After that you can go to libraries part in my above answer.

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply :) I have a very large dataset with respect to Name how to overcome the problem of manual entry of data

Comment: If you have a large data set you can read your file instead of the manual entry. I will update my answer above.

Comment: <a href='http://www.ImageFolks.com/img-51d1f6cc015c7.html'><img src='http://www.ImageFolks.com/upload/small/2013/07/01/51d1f6cc0158f.JPG' alt='image' /></a>

Comment: in the image if you see the x axis is having names which are getting overlapped similarly in the case of y axis as well can you help me in arranging them properly please

Comment: Can you put the link of your data file so that I can work on that ? For example you can put your data on dropbox.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not allowed to share data :(

Comment: Ok, that's fine. let's say you have your plot represented by `p<- ggplot(...)`. In the next line type the following: `p+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+ylim(10,85)` You should get somehow better than previous results.

Comment: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale getting this error

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i could solve the problem with the x -axis but the problem is still present with the y axis